# video tag event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a video player using video tag.
What I what from player is when someone click on video, if it is playing it stop if it is not playing on click it start playing

Below here is my code :

```
 window.onlaod=init();

 function init(){

    BarLenght= 900;
    video = document.getElementById('vid');

    video.addEventListener('click', playOrPause , false);
    alert("hello");

}
function playOrPause(){
     if((!video.paused) && (!video.ended))
     {
        video.pause();
    }
    else{
        if((video.paused) && (!video.ended))
        {
            video.play();
        }
        else{
            video.currentTime=0;
             video.play();
        }
      }

 }
```

but it is not working, Can anyone have idea why it not working..?

Comment: "not working" is not a clear problem statement. What is happening? What does the console in the browser's developer tools say?

Comment: video.addEventListener('click', playOrPause , false);
is not working 
i used alert statement to to check where is problem
when alert statement is placed before " video,addEventListener" statement it pop ups 
but it is placed after "" video.addEventListener" statement it doesn't pop up.

Comment: Just "not working". No error messages in the JS console when you try to find the event handler in the first place? Have you checked that the `init()` function runs at all?

Comment: init() function is runs .. details are following
video.addEventListener('click', playOrPause , false); is not working i used alert statement to to check where is problem when alert statement is placed before " video,addEventListener" statement it pop ups but it is placed after "" video.addEventListener" statement it doesn't pop up

Comment: … and what does the Console say? Does it give an error message?

Comment: By writing this "window.addEventListener('load', init);" it start working 

can you explain the difference between
 "window.addEventListener('load', init);"
 and 
" window.onload=init;

Comment: You wrote `window.onload=init()`, not `window.onload=init`.

Comment: i tired with window.onload=init

Answer (score 0):

Window.onload is misspelled. You may want to try looking at that.

Comment: Doesn't actually matter as the return value of `init()` isn't a function.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly where the fault is, but there's a few things in your code that will definitely cause issues. Your `onload` is mispelled. Also, your `video` variable is assigned within the init. You haven't declared a global var for it, so that may cause the issue. By design in JS, variables not prefixed with `var` will be assumed global, but you should never assume this to be true. Always declare your variables in the scope you intend to use them. The following may do the trick...

```
var video = null;

function init(){

    BarLength = 900; //this was misspelled, also I'm not sure what it refers to...
    video = document.getElementById('vid');

    video.addEventListener('click', playOrPause , false);
    alert("hello");

}

function playOrPause(){
    if(!video.paused && !video.ended)
    {
        video.pause();
    } else{
        if(video.paused && !video.ended) {
            video.play();
        } else{
            video.currentTime=0;
            video.play();
        }
      }

 }

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

Comment: "  BarLength = 900; //this was misspelled, also I'm not sure what it refers to..."  this is for latter use

By writing this "window.addEventListener('load', init);" it start working

can you explain the difference between "window.addEventListener('load', init);"
 and 
" window.onload=init;

BTW thanks

Comment: Your `window.onload = init` should have worked as well, though you had it misspelled as `window.onlaod`. The difference has to do with event bubbling and scope. This article explains the differences in detail: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="play()" type="button">Play</button>
<button onclick="pause()" type="button">Pause</button>
<button onclick="stop()" type="button">Stop</button><br>

<video id="vid" width="" height="">
  <source src="/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Error!
</video>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("vid");

function play() {
    vid.play();
}

function pause() {
    vid.pause();
}

function stop() {
    vid.src="/video.mp4";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```